# Adding Edit Properties To First Document Callout Menu In SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 page with a document library.  When the user clicks on a document "..." callout, I want to add Edit Properties to that menu instead of forcing the user to click on the second "..." to get to that option.  Can anyone help me do this with putting some Javascript into the Script Editor web part for the page?

TIA!

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going through all of that, SharePoint offers a quick edit option for your document library.  Go to your library settings -> choose the view -> and add the edit (link to edit item) column.

Simplest way to denote to your users a quicker edit feature.

[image]

Comment: I'm speechless.  :)  Thanks Flat Banana!!